# java @webservice receives null parameter values if namespace prefix not provided in request

Tags: java, web-services, parameters, null

java @webservice receives null parameter values if namespace prefix not provided in request

webservice client is sending request like below and I have to make it work
        I tried to remove target namespace as @WebService(targetNamespace= "")

```
    and

    @WebMethod()
        @WebResult(name = "fusionIntegrationResponse", targetNamespace = "")
        @RequestWrapper(targetNamespace = "")
        @ResponseWrapper(targetNamespace = "")
        @Override`enter code here`
        public FusionIntegrationResponse activateFusion(String agentId, String ucn, String companyId) {

    WSDL always add targetnamespace and if I remove explicitly it says invalid definition.

    **webservice receives null values for all parameter for following soap request message.**

    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <activateFusion xmlns="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/">
    <arg0>F3015505</arg0>
    <arg1>96334</arg1>
    <arg2>15</arg2>
    </activateFusion>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>


    **following works fine**
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ws:activateFusion>
            <arg0>F3015505</arg0>
           <arg1>96334</arg1>
           <arg2>15</arg2>
          </ws:activateFusion>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your working request, it looks like your arguments don't have a namespace, so the following should work:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <activateFusion xmlns="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/">
      <arg0 xmlns="">F3015505</arg0>
      <arg1 xmlns="">96334</arg1>
      <arg2 xmlns="">15</arg2>
    </activateFusion>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and it did work but I want to process following request. what should i change at my side to make it work. <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <activateFusion xmlns="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/">
    <arg0>F3015505</arg0>
    <arg1>96334</arg1>
    <arg2>15</arg2>
    </activateFusion>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: or if i can make changes to my webservice to process following request

Comment: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Body><activateFusion xmlns="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/"><arg0 xmlns="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/">SADMIN</arg0><arg1 xmlns="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/">1737834</arg1><arg2 xmlns="http://ws.fusionintegration.service.fnb.co.za/">15</arg2></activateFusion></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>